# GCP BQML: how to view or edit public holidays data of a country while working on ARIMA model

Tags: google-bigquery, time-series, arima

Referring to BQML documents [The CREATE MODEL statement for ARIMA_PLUS models](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-time-series), we can include public holidays of a country (e.g. `HOLIDAY_REGION = 'US'`) while using BQML with time series model. It has also shown the holiday data in the US region for the year 2022-2023 ("Holiday data" section).

My question is how I can `view` or `edit` the holiday data (e.g. primary_date, preholiday_days and postholiday_days) of a particular country for my own BQML time series modelling? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I believe it is currently not possible to view or edit these holiday periods in BQML at the current time.

Comment: Thanks, Ben for your reply. Wonder the holiday data is stored somewhere within GCP platform if it is not in BQML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With BigQuery ML's [latest release](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#July_12_2023), you are now able to view and edit the holiday data.

To view the built in holiday, you can inspect the bigquery-public-data.ml_datasets.holidays_and_events_for_forecasting table. Or you can feed your ARIMA model to the [ML.HOLIDAY_INFO](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-holiday-info) TVF.

To customize the holiday, you can feed custom holiday data in the [same CREATE MODEL statement with new syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-time-series#holiday_statement). [This tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-series-forecasting-holidays-tutorial) also has a step by step walk through.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Honglin. For the setting of custom_holiday, it requires consistent window size for the same holiday_name across the years. However, at region=MY, we get an extra day off if the actual holiday falls on a Sunday. Hence, for the same holiday_name, the number of days off might be different for different years.